# Do static locks work across different children classes?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, static, locking

If I have

```
abstract class Parent
{
    static object staticLock = new object();

    public void Method1()
    {
        lock(staticLock)
        {
            Method2();
        }
    }

    protected abstract Method2();
}

class Child1 : Parent
{
    protected override Method2()
    {
          // Do something ...
    }
}

class Child2 : Parent
{
    protected override Method2()
    {
          // Do something else ...
    }
}
```

Will calls to `new Child1().Method1()` and `new Child2().Method1()` use the same lock?

Comment: And staticLock is "private" (default for members http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx), so can't be accessed by child classes.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I just want to garantee that only one `Method2` is being called at any single instant, I don't need the child classes to access it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I'm not following you. The idea here is to have a *public* method that is *not overridable* that ensures that *callers* always take the lock. That way the authors of derived classes can just implement Method2 without having to remember "oh yeah, I've got to take a lock here". This pattern eliminates one kind of error but of course it produces opportunities for another; now authors of those derived classes need to know that the parent class lock is taken, and to not cause a deadlock on it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: The whole idea is to *prevent* the derived classes from messing with this lock. The down side of that is, as I mentioned in my previous comment, now they need to know that the lock is there so as to not cause a deadlock, even though they cannot access the lock.

Comment: Makes sense. Yes, as everyone is saying. Suggestion: you should have named your Method2 in a way that does not make it look like sibling of Method1 (i.e. MethodImpl).

Comment: @EricLippert: sorry, I missed the call of `Method2` inside of `Method1`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. A derived class does not get a *new* copy of the static data from the base class.

However, this is not the case with *generic* classes. If you say:

```
class Base<T>
{
    protected static object sync = new object();
    ...
}

class Derived1 : Base<int> { ... }
class Derived2 : Base<int> { ... }
class Derived3 : Base<string> { ... }
class Derived4 : Base<string> { ... }
class Derived5 : Base<object> { ... }
class Derived6 : Base<object> { ... }
```

instances of Derived1 and Derived2 have the same sync object. Instances of Derived3 and Derived4 have the same sync object. Instances of Derived5 and Derived6 have the same sync object. But the three sync objects are all different objects.

Comment: Eric, since generic code is jitted once for all reference types, does that mean that `class Derived4 : Base<FileInfo> { ... }` would share the same sync object with `Derived3`?

Comment: @phoog: Good question. No; different constructions of a generic type are *different types*. `Base<string>` and `Base<FileInfo>` are different types, so `Base<string>.sync` and `Base<FileInfo>.sync` are different fields. The fact that as an implementation detail, the jitter will jit the *methods* of `Base<string>` and `Base<FileInfo>` once and re-use the jitted state does not at all change the fact that they are *different types*.

Comment: Thanks Eric, the idea that `Base<string>.sync` and `Base<FileInfo>.sync` might be the same field was rather disturbing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, generally speaking, `lock` on `static` objects protect data for all instances of your class.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, **or a private
>   static object variable to protect data common to all instances**.

Answer (score 2):

To add to ken2k's answer: [Yes] ... unless it's marked as `[ThreadStatic]` (which obviously isn't the case here).

Comment: I didn't know that. Very important to another problem I was dealing with.

Comment: Indeed, a thread static lock would rather defeat the purpose of having the lock in the first place!