# How to refactor these locks?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, concurrency, locking

The naive solution, to move the lock to the `Parent` class, has a different behaviour: I will not be able to call `new Child1().Method1()` and `new Child2().Method1()` simultaneously.

Is there any way to refactor the code below?

```
abstract class Parent
{
    protected abstract Method1();
}

class Child1 : Parent
{
    static object staticLock = new object();

    public void Method1()
    {
        lock(staticLock)
        {
          // Do something ...
        }
    }
}

class Child2 : Parent
{
    static object staticLock = new object();

    public void Method1()
    {
        lock(staticLock)
        {
          // Do something else ...
        }
    }
}
```

I'm asking this because it's not only 2 child classes, so the real problem is bigger.

Comment: If the scope of locking is correct (e.g. within the specific derived classes), why refactor it at all?

Comment: Why are your locking objects static?

Comment: @Domenic those classes represent physical machines, the instances are clients, only one client can control a machine at any given time

Comment: why are you refactoring this?  What the purpose of this code?

Comment: I think this is continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198087/do-static-locks-work-across-different-children-classes

Comment: What does the method that invokes `Method1` look like?

Comment: @XMLforDummies - Depending on the context in which each `Method1` is invoked, it might be possible perform the lock outside of each implementation or at least handle the locking another way.

Comment: @M.Babcock The invoking code can't see which implementation is instantiated without reflection.

Comment: @XMLforDummies - That's sort of the point. The invoking code wouldn't need to know which implementation is being called, only that `Method1` needs to be locked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a method implemented by each child class that provides lock policy and move Method1 to base class as in your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198087/do-static-locks-work-across-different-children-classes) question.

```
class Parent
{
  public void Method1()
  {
    using(acquireLock())
    {
      Method1Impl();
    }
  }
  protected abstract IDisposable acquireLock();
  protected abstract void Method1Impl();
}
class Child : Parent
{
   protected override IDisposable acquireLock()
   {
      // return some class that does appropriate locking 
      // and in Dispose releases the lock.
      // may even be no-op locking.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works

```
abstract class Parent
{
    protected abstract object StaticLock { get; }

    public void Method()
    {
        lock(staticLock)
        {
            MethodImpl();
        }
    }

    protected abstract MethodImpl();
}

class Child1 : Parent
{
    private static object staticLock = new object();

    protected override object StaticLock { get { return staticLock; } }

    protected override MethodImpl()
    {
          // Do something ...
    }
}

class Child2 : Parent
{
    private static object staticLock = new object();

    protected override object StaticLock { get { return staticLock; } }

    protected override MethodImpl()
    {
          // Do something else ...
    }
}
```

Comment: At first glance looks fine to me and simple than mine.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov But I'm concerned with implicit copies. If the `staticLock` object gets copied, it's efficacy as a lock object is lost.

Comment: Object is always passed by reference, as long as you don't replace "staticLock" object (`staticObject=new Object()`) it should be fine.